# The XML parse error 0xc00ce01d occurred

Tags: sql-server

i am getting xml parser error. how to handle this situation.

### my script was

```
DECLARE @xmlDoc VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @handle INT
SET @xmlDoc = N'
<DELETED>
  <JID>41185</JID>
  <WID>0</WID>
  <AccountReference>LH169</AccountReference>
  <OEReference>Ari002</OEReference>
  <InvoiceNumber>0</InvoiceNumber>
  <OrderPlacedBy>Mark Catterall</OrderPlacedBy>
  <Specialist>0FFICINA MOTTAUTO</Specialist>
  <UserName xsi:nil="true" />
</DELETED>'

Declare @SqlQuery varchar(max)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @xmlDoc
SET @SqlQuery ='Select '
SELECT  @SqlQuery = @SqlQuery + LocalName  + ',' FROM OPENXML (@handle, '/DELETED', 1) 
WHere  localname not like '#%' And id>0 And localname <> 'nil'
Set @SqlQuery = Substring(@SqlQuery,0,LEN(@SqlQuery)-1) + ' From tablename'
print @SqlQuery
--Exec @SqlQuery
--EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

i am getting error for `<UserName xsi:nil="true" />` how to handle this situation. what to rectify in the script.

thank

Comment: SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005+? And you want a table back from the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 0xC00CE01D: Reference to undeclared
>   namespace prefix.

Changing the XML to this will take care of that

```
<DELETED xmlns:xsi="uri">
  <JID>41185</JID>
  <WID>0</WID>
  <AccountReference>LH169</AccountReference>
  <OEReference>Ari002</OEReference>
  <InvoiceNumber>0</InvoiceNumber>
  <OrderPlacedBy>Mark Catterall</OrderPlacedBy>
  <Specialist>0FFICINA MOTTAUTO</Specialist>
  <UserName xsi:nil="true" />
</DELETED>'
```

Using the XML data type you could do this instead:

```
declare @xml xml = 
'<DELETED xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <JID>41185</JID>
  <WID>0</WID>
  <AccountReference>LH169</AccountReference>
  <OEReference>Ari002</OEReference>
  <InvoiceNumber>0</InvoiceNumber>
  <OrderPlacedBy>Mark Catterall</OrderPlacedBy>
  <Specialist>0FFICINA MOTTAUTO</Specialist>
  <UserName xsi:nil="true" />
</DELETED>'

declare @SqlQuery varchar(max)
set @SqlQuery ='Select '

select 
  @SqlQuery = @SqlQuery + N.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)')+','
from @xml.nodes('DELETED/*') as T(N)

set @SqlQuery = substring(@SqlQuery,0,len(@SqlQuery)-1) + ' from tablename'

print @SqlQuery
```

Comment: yes u said right but now changing the xml i am getting select statement like...Select xsi,JID,WID,AccountReference,OEReference,InvoiceNumber,OrderPlacedBy,Specialist,UserName,ni From tablename
but i dont want to show xsi in my sql so please tell me what to do.

Comment: @Thomas you could add `And localname <> 'xsi'` to the where clause.